# Collada Export Options Panel Not Showing in 2.82

Tags: export, collada

Just started using 2.82.

When I try to export a model as Collada in *File > Export > Collada/Dafault (.dae)* I no longer see the Export Collada panel with Operator Presets show up.

Am I missing a preference config or an Add-On?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. The panel is now part of the File Browser panel. I had not expanded the right hand side of the browser panel. I just noticed a little '<' at the top right and that popped open the panel with Operator Presets and the other options.

Comment: You can also click on the gear icon for the same effect.